# Do I have to install a monitor driver to access full display modes of a monitor

Tags: windows, resolution

I bought a `Lenovo ThinkVision 23 inches` monitor today and I checked the resolution of the monitor from the official website and it happens to be so big, its resolution is `1680*1050`,} after checking this with Windows, Windows says that the resolution is `1366*768` and I can't seem to edit that combo box and change the value to `1920*1080`, is this the maximum resolution that windows support for large screens, or is it the `Intel HD graphics driver` that seems to have a problem?

I really want the physical resolution of the screen to match the one Windows reads. Then after reading the installation guide, there is a driver that should be installed for the monitor. The monitor driver in Device Manager is showing a generic PnP monitor. Is this what is making me unable to select a different display resolution? And then the guide pdf has a note: "If your system has been previously configured with a screen whose resolution is lower, you might want to re attach that monitor and change before connecting the new monitor"

The model of the monitor is Lenovo l2251

Comment: Hi, could you edit your question with your system information, especially processor, number of screens and graphics connectivity (hdmi, dp, vga ...)

Comment: Most likely your monitor is only 1366*768 as the Thinkvision is a **range** of displays of different sizes and resolutions, or you are duplicating a laptop display that is limited to 1366 * 768. More information is required, specifically the exact model of the monitor, what you are connecting to and so on.

Comment: The manual or booklet that came with the monitor should list the *native resolution*. Also, is this a laptop or desktop computer? Check intel for CPU video support ( https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023781/graphics.html )

Comment: Its a desktop computer

Comment: @Mokubai, yeah the resolution is 1366*768.. can a video cad improve that?

Comment: A video card cannot change a monitor. Please [edit] your question to provide the details as requested in the comments above. We need more information.

Comment: Does resolution affect gaming?

Answer (score 3):

> is 1366*768 .... the maximum resolution that windows support for large
> screens?

No, not at all. Indeed Windows can support even higher resolutions than 1920 * 1080.

Either update or replace the Video Driver you have. Also update the Monitor Driver and possibly even update the machine BIOS.

I have a customer with that monitor (or very close) on a Windows Desktop computer running at 1920x1080.

Also check the resolution of the Host machine display. Most newer machines (but not all) handle 1920 x 1080.